# gRPC bidirectional streaming client sometimes close rpc unexpected EOF to server behind Nginx Ingress

Tags: digital-ocean, nlb, nginx-ingress, amazon-eks, grpc

I am faced with the issue that a gRPC Client in Bidirectional streaming call to the server behind an AWS NLB, nginx ingress controller **sometimes** throws er "**close rpc error: code = Internal desc = unexpected EOF**".

Here is my setup:

- **Golang pod gRPC server 1 replica (1)** running on EKS cluster (in Singapore)
- Server exposes to nginx ingress behind AWS NLB (nginx controllers pods are deployed with **3 replicas** in **3 different on-demand nodes**, and the AWS NLB only **targets on-demand nodes** - not spot nodes)
- **The client (2)** is written in Golang as well running in the 3 Digital Ocean droplets with 1 instance per droplet (in Singapore) connected to the server through a domain pointed to NLB.
- The client is also a gRPC server that pushes data to a **Socket server (3)** (in the same VPC in Digital Ocean with (2) - a private connection - 3 droplets - 2 instances per droplet) by bidirectional streaming.

The error is thrown by (2) **sometimes** with one of the 2 below errors:

```
close rpc error: code = Internal desc = unexpected EOF

close rpc error: code = Internal desc = stream terminated by RST_STREAM with error code: INTERNAL_ERROR
```

Logs in nginx:

```
[error] 25#25: *599548 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while sending to client
```

I also found the magic error only came from the **(2) that connected with (3) when (3) has users connect to by socket connections**. The others (2) that connected to (3) that **don't have any client connected** did not throw any error, but when I pointed the domain to (3) to move the client to them, they got the errors.

I also tried to disable proxy_buffering or enable it in the **Nginx Configmap**, but nothing happened.
Here is my nginx config:

```
proxy_buffering off;
....
location ...
                    client_max_body_size                    0;
                    proxy_connect_timeout                   60s;                                                                            
                    proxy_send_timeout                      3600s;                                                                           
                    proxy_read_timeout                      3600s;                                                                           
                                                                                                                                           
                    proxy_buffering                         off;                                                                           
                    proxy_buffer_size                       64k;                                                                           
                    proxy_buffers                           4 64k;                                                                         
                                                                                                                                           
                    proxy_max_temp_file_size                1024m;                                                                         
                                                                                                                                           
                    proxy_request_buffering                 on;                                                                            
                    proxy_http_version                      1.1;                                                                           
                                                                                                                                           
                    proxy_cookie_domain                     off;                                                                           
                    proxy_cookie_path                       off;                                                                           
                                                                                                                                                                                  
                    proxy_next_upstream                     error timeout;                                                                 
                    proxy_next_upstream_timeout             0;                                                                             
                    proxy_next_upstream_tries               3;                                                                             
                                                                                                                                           
                    grpc_pass grpc://upstream_balancer;                                                                                    
                                                                                                                                           
                    proxy_redirect                          off;
```

Does anyone have faced this error or have any idea? Thank you!

**[Update]**
I tried to connect to server (1) using K8S service NodePort, and it worked. So now I can confirm that the problem comes from nginx ingress. Is there any wrong with my Nginx configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to change grpc_send_timeout, grpc_read_timeout?
https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/grpc/#notes-on-using-responserequest-streams

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/568079)

Comment: yeah, I tried but it not worked. Then I start to detect if there are any clients (3) that have a lot of delay messages when connected to (2) (the buffer I detect in the server (2)), so I clear the delay buffer from that client, and it not happened so frequent anymore. But I'm still confused about why I fixed the connection from (3) to (2), it solved the error EOF came from the connection (2) to (1)